# Docker persistent volume on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, persistent-volumes

I'm deploying services to GCP and I want to persist the database and logs.

The VM's local storage is not considered.

How can I mount the GCP disk/bucket to the containers?

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    image: mybackend:latest
    volumes:
      - logs-data:/path/to/logs

  database:
    image: postgres:12.6-alpine
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - logs-data:/var/log/postgresql

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: ??
    driver_opts: ??

  logs-data:
    driver: ??
    driver_opts: ??
```

The `gcePersistentDisk` is for Kubernetes only.

Comment: if your disk attached to VM you can use it I think by just changing the mount path in docker-compose and writing all the data inside the disk.

Comment: @HarshManvar The GCP disk can be only mounted to one VM at the same time. I mounted it from 'VM instances' > 'VM instance details' > 'edit' > 'Additional disks'

Comment: Are you able to set up this configuration in your local environment? if so, can you share how you did?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I use `nfs` in the development environment. However, I cannot find the document using `nfs` to connect to GCP disk/storage bucket.

Comment: Have a look to [memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore) ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [gcsfuse](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse) to create a docker volume which stores data in google cloud storage.

1. First install gcsfuse as mention in [gcsfuse] docs.
2. Create a google cloud storage bucket
3. Mount the bucket on your local filesystem using gcsfuse
4. Bind mount of this filesystem
   5

Answer (score 1):

The Docker built-in driver `local` only supports `NFS` and `bind` (bind to local file system).

The `bind` is not considered a solution because containers will not be in the same node.

These are possible solutions from Google:

1. Create another container to be the `NFS` host
2. Create multiple containers to compose a [GlusterFS](https://www.gluster.org/) cluster, and use `NFS` to connect to it
3. Install 3rd-party driver plugin [REX Ray](https://github.com/rexray/rexray) (the repo is inactive)